# Change specific data from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The exercise is, to create an arraylist for a class, where a User can enter "Guestnumber" + "Guestname" + "Guestemail".

In the menu you could remove an existing "Guest" with all the Information. Thats the code for it: (it works)

```
 public void gastAendern() {
  System.out.println("Guestnumber to delete:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();
    for (Gast test : verwaltungG) {
        int nummer = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if (test.getgNr() == nummer) {
         verwaltungG.remove(test);
            a = 1;
            break;
       }
      }
      if(a==0) {
          System.out.println("Guestnumber is not used");
```

`verwaltungG` is the ArrayList

`Gast` is the class for get+set

But now I got a problem to change an existing Guest, like for example:

I ask to type in the Guestnumber OR the Guestname OR the Guestmail to change it (I have to do it for all 3). So I have really no idea how to change it. I looked through Stackoverflow, google etc. but it only shows how to change them with List.set, but I don't know if it works with my kind of Problem, because I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar as you are doing for delete, instead of `remove` - you need to change the details you need update :

```
System.out.println("Guestnumber to update :");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.next();
for (Gast test : verwaltungG) {
  int nummer = Integer.parseInt(input);
  if (test.getgNr() == nummer) {
     System.out.println("Enter new guest name for guest number : "+nummer );
     String name = sc.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter new guest email for guest number : "+nummer );
     String email = sc.nextLine();


     // now update the details
     test.setName(name);
     test.setEmail(email);
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Holy it worked, Thank you very much Abubakkar Rangara :)